# Rendering Differences in FF IE and Chrome

Tags: css

I am redesigning a website and finding problems with small rendering differences between IE FF and Chrome.  Am using CSS and .  Is there any way to avoid these differences?

Also, even when I fix the diffences, FF still ocassionally renders incorrectly on some computers.  It doesn't appear to be resolution related but only ocurrs on laptops with 15" screens or smaller.

Any ideas or input welcome as I would prefer not to have these differences in the first place to avoid having to make numerous tweaks to fix.  Thanks

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. Rendering differences aren't uncommon, and it's impossible to give you one answer that addresses any possible difference.

Comment: I don't think the question should be "list the differences", but rather "how can the [user experience] differences be quickly and easily identified".

Answer (score 1):

Different browsers, and different versions of browsers render HTML and CSS differently.

There is no one way to create a web page that will make it look the same in all browsers.

You simply must pick a subset of browsers you wish to support (such as IE6+, FF3.5+, Chrome 9+) and make them look ***as good as possible*** in those browsers.

You will never get it exactly the same in all browsers.

Comment: Okay, so given this advice -- how can one quickly and consistently check a rendering in a bunch of browsers? Are there any good "test" setups or methodologies for this?

Comment: @pst, http://browsershots.org/ (free, average) and https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html (costs, good) are to quicker ways to cross browser test.

Comment: thanks for the info about Adobe Browserlab.  Had a quick look and think it will be very useful.  It is free till Apr 2012...